# Symlink creating a nested subdirectory

Tags: symlink, ln

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong today with trying to create.

Inside my current directory, I recreated an empty directory called `input`. I would like to symlink this to

```
../../../../opt/build/db/output
```

So within my current directory, I did

```
ln -s ../../../../opt/build/db/output input
```

But when I do `ls -l input`, I see

```
output -> ../../../../opt/build/db/output
```

It created a directory within `input` called `output` that's symlinke to `../../../../opt/build/db/output` , but this is not what I want. I don't want an `output` directory within `input`. I want `input` directly symlinekd to `../../../../opt/build/db/output` . What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty sure this is how I've always created symlinks.

I also removed the `input` folder, and then ran the command again and it worked as expected. I guess I can't have the existing `input` directory?

Comment: Why not use absolute paths instead of relative paths?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I'm copying a symlnk structure that's in the existing codebase and it uses relative paths. not sure why

Answer (score 4):

The mistake you made was to create `input` under your current directory before invoking your `ln -s` command to link it.  `ln` wants to create the link from scratch, not "link" existing directories together.

Comment: I see. I could've sworn in the past when I used `ln -s`, I create the directory first and then try to symlink, but maybe I'm misremembering. With that said, is there a way to link existing directories together like I tried todo?

Comment: No, when creating a link, whether it's a hard link or soft/symbolic link, the entity being created (the last item on the `ln` command line) cannot exist yet.